# retrieve all values in column exceeding 5 strings - pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in dataframe - df where all values should be length of 5 strings/characters but due to an error in my code, some have erroneous values and length of strings is either below 5 or greater than 5. Is there a way to just retrieve these columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this work for you? This will return a dataframe where values meet the condition.

```
new_DF= your_df[your_df['COLUMN TO CHECK HERE'].str.len() != 5]
print(new_DF)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I will be needing this down the road!

Answer (score 2):

For your next question, please provide an example `df` and an expected output.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1, 2, 3], 'b' : ["jasdjdj", "abcde", "hmmamamam"]})
df[df.b.str.len() != 5]
#gives:

   a          b
0  1    jasdjdj
2  3  hmmamamam
```

Comment: Then I think your question should say: "Is there a way to retrieve just these ROWS?" (instead of columns)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a simple masking operation:

```
filter = lambda string: len(string) == 5
mask = df[col_to_filter].apply(filter, 1) # Return a boolean vector
new_df = df[mask].copy() # Create a new dataframe
```

You can apply an opposite filter to find items that aren't length 5 on your original dataframe.

For more details on `df.apply()` look here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: thanks for showing this method, this is something I will need down the road!